# setChildIndex to value directly below target object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, layer

Looking to set an objects index value to -1 that of the specified object.

```
this.setChildIndex(box, circle.index-1);
```

I thought this would work but I apparently I am wrong.
I am trying to get the box directly below the circle index which has an index value that changes constantly. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the getChildIndex method I was able to accomplish this
 
solution:

```
this.setChildIndex(box, this.getChildIndex(circle)-1);
```